# EF.Core querying related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I had some trouble with getting the 1to1 relations working in EF.Core,

I have these models:

```
public class IncomingData
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public History History { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("IncomingDataId")]
    public IncomingData IncomingData { get; set; }
}
```

And the History Database seems to correctly store the ForeignKey as IncommingDataId

[image]

But when I execute the following code into my controller

```
var histories = _db.Histories.Where(x => x.IMEI == device.IMEI).OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp);
```

`histories.IncomingData` is always `null`

So I had to do some *hackish* workaround to have the `histories` contain `IncomingData`

```
foreach (var h in histories) {
    var incomingDataRecord = _db.IncomingData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.History == h);
}
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong somewhere :) If for information is needed, I'll add it

Comment: use `Include` method to get `IncomingData`: `_db.IncomingData.Include(x => x.IncomingData).FirstOrDefault(x => x.History == h)`

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh This works :+1:

Comment: I am waiting for confirmation of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't Include the related entity object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

```
var histories = _db.Histories
    .Where(x => x.IMEI == device.IMEI)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
    .Include(x => x.IncomingData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `History` class should be like this:

```
public class History
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public IncomingData IncomingData { get; set; }
}
```

What this means is, you're using the same property (`Id`) to refer to both entities. If you can, you can give them different names by assigning a `[Column]` attribute.

Comment: It took some time testing, but this doesn't solve the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain without running it, but I think you are looking for this...

```
public class IncomingData
{
[Key]
[Required]
public int Id { get; set; }

...

public History History { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

...

[InverseProperty("Id")]
public IncomingData IncomingData { get; set; }
}
```

and you retrieve it with...

```
var histories = _db.Histories.Where(x => x.IMEI == device.IMEI).Include("IncomingData").OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp);
```

assuming IMEI and Timestamp are properties of History

Comment: Why the `[InverseProperty("Id")]` or am I missing something? A `.Include` works for me

Comment: Just being explicit about the relationship between IncomingData and History.  I prefer to be explicit, even if EF can "figure it out".  Seen too many upgrades over the decades change a default behavior.